# numpy array with different datatypes

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I would like to know if numpy array can hold different datatypes.
For example, I have this array:

```py
[[2,3,'this is a string', 3.3],
 [13,8,'this is a string', 4.2]]
```

What I would like to have: column #0, #1 int, column #2 as string and column #3 as float.

Comment: Sure you can - [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html)

Comment: You can, but it's easier to use pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/ which is numpy compatible

Comment: If you tell what you need the array for, you might get better answers

Comment: So, it's better to use pandas for my porpouse.